# Encrypt a string in PHP, Decrypt it in C#?

Tags: c#, php, .net, winforms, encryption-symmetric

In the action.php page, I have a string that I want to store in mysql but I want to encrypt it before inserting it to the db

```
 $data = "Hello World";
 $data = Encrypt_This_String($data,"ABCD"); // abcd is a key
 // now I insert this string into MySQL database
```

In the other side, I need to get back this string from my C#.NET application, so I need to do something like this :

```
 string myStr = getMyString(); // where getMyString() is a function that get the encrypted string from db

 myStr = Decrypt_String(myStr,"ABCD");
```

I need that myStr hold the value "Hello World"

Could someone please give me an encryption algorithm that is based on a key and can be used in both PHP and C# ?

Comment: How secure does the encryption have to be?

Comment: AES-CBC together with HMAC-SHA-256 can be implemented using the libs included with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) to encrypt the data from PHP, with e.g. AES in CBC mode as the cipher; there is example code on the documentation page.

Then decrypt from C# using [`AesManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) or [`AesCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx), both pages on MSDN have example code.

Comment: You probably need a MAC as well. CBC without MAC can often be broken using padding oracles.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Rijndael (AES 128) :

[PHP- AES128 Example](https://gist.github.com/1077723)

[C# AES128 Example](http://softwaredevelopment.gr/440/rijndael-aes-128-decryption-in-c/)

Comment: The C# example uses ECB and ASCII encoding for the key. The php code is lacking a MAC and doesn't have an IV. Those aren't good examples to follow.